# AngularJs Global Message Service and Authentication

Tags: angularjs

I have a message system in place that has two methods `show` and `clear`. I want to use $http interceptors in order to handle authentication because my server is smart enough to know whether a user is authenticated or not per request and will tell me so by sending me me a status response of `401` or `403`. So, I have something like this for my interceptor:

```
myModule.factory('statusInterceptor', function($location, MessageService, urlManager){
    return {
        responseError: function(response){
            switch(response.status){
                ...
                case 401:
                case 403:
                    $location.url(urlManager.reverse('Login'));
                    MessageService.show('Dude, you need to log in first.');
                    break;
                case 500:
                    break;
                ...
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

That works just fine on either a `401` or a `403` response as it shows the message as expected. The problem I'm having is clearing the message whenever the user logs in or goes to another route. I have a `MainCtrl` that is in charge of almost everything and one of the things that it is looking after is `$routeChangeStart`. My thought being that the view is changing to a different view, so I want to clear the messages at the beginning of the route switch. So, in my `MainCtrl` I have:

```
myControllers.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MessageService){
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        MessageService.clear();
    });
});
```

Here's the way I expect the app to react:

1. A user has tried to do something without being authenticated by sending a request to the server
2. The server responds with either a `401` or `403` because the user is not authenticated.
3. The `responseError` function is fired calling my `$location.url()` method which, in my mind, should fire the `$routeChangeStart`, or even `$locationChangeStart`, events (I've tried both).

   - This should in turn fire my `MessageService.clear()` method and clear out any previous message.
4. The user is finally redirected to the login page with the correct `"Dude, you need to log in first."` message.

What really happens:

The user is redirected to the login page as expected, however, the error message does not display. When setting certain debug points in Chrome, I see that `$location.path()` is called immediately followed by `MessageService.show('Dude...')`, finally followed by the `MessageService.clear()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you like this approach to that problem

http://jsfiddle.net/jYCPQ/1/

```
module.factory('authenticationInterceptor', function ($q, navigator, MessageService) {
    return {
        responseError: function (response) {
            switch (response.status) {
                case 403:
                    navigator.navigateTo("/login").then(function () {
                        MessageService.show('Dude, you need to log in first.');
                    });
                    return $q.reject(response);
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
});
module.factory("navigator", function ($location, $rootScope, $q) {

    var navigateTo = function (url) {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        $location.url(url);
        var unbind = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            defered.resolve();
            unbind();
        })
        return defered.promise;
    }
    return {
        navigateTo: navigateTo
    }
});
```

regards

Comment: I like the usage of the $q promise. I didn't know you could use it for  anything other than request/response events. So, a $q is just an easier/neater way to do callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution and ended up with something like this:

In my interceptor function:

```
myModule.factory('statusInterceptor', function($rootScope){
    return {
        responseError: function(response){
            switch(response.status){
                ...
                case 401:
                case 403:
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:notAuthenticated');
                    break;
                case 500:
                    break;
                ...
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

And in my controller:

```
myControllers.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, MessageService){
    $scope.$on('event:notAuthenticated', function(){
        $location.path(urlManager.reverse('Login'));
        var remove_this_binding = $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
            messageService.show('Dude, you need to log in first.');
            remove_this_binding();
        });
    });
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        messageService.clear();
    });
});
```

I was trying to find an angular way of having a callback associated with `$location`'s path change and this is the best I could come up with. If anyone else has a better solution, I'm all ears.